# Telegram бот на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Всем добрый день. Пишу телеграм бота на Python. Возник вопрос, как сделать надпись в чате с пользователем, входящую. Пользователь еще ничео не написал боту, даже /start, а надпись уже есть. Есть фото. Заранее большое спасибо! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В настройках BotFather меняется с помощью `/setdescription` — изменить описание робота, представляющее собой короткий текст с описанием бота.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: если ты "зачал" бота в BotFather то там можно это установить. поищи в настройках.

Comment: Это делается в настройках бота через @botfather.